# Replace content with pure CSS

Tags: css, margin

### Background:

I am trying to find a way to replace or swap some *old content* with some *new content* with pure CSS. I found a way that **works** but I want to improve it.

I decide to use a combination of [pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements), [negative margins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin#%3Clength%3E), and [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) in order to do the following

1. Hide *old content* using `color:transparent`
2. Add *new content* inside the `content:` property of the
   pseudo-element `:after`
3. override `color:transparent` for the pseudo-element by giving it a `color`
4. Use **negative** `margin-left` to bring the content of the `:after`
   element - the *new content* - on top of the now transparent *old
   content* **<~ my question is about this particular point.**

The end result is that the *new content* **sits perfectly on top of the *old transparent content* and blends really well**. The old content - an `<a>` element in my case - still functions as intended.

### The general problem:

While looking for the best way to find out how much negative `margin-left` to make this a little bit more systematic to use I found that the best is set the negative margin to match the length of the *old content* which makes sense.

CSS has such a thing.

I found that there is a CSS length unit known as `ch` and it has decent [cross browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=ch-unit)

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#ch) says:

> [ch] Represents the width, or more precisely the advance measure, of the glyph '0' (zero, the Unicode character U+0030) in the element's font.

### The specific problem

Well my understanding is that not all characters in a font have the same width as the glyph '0' of that font, if they actually do then I don't understand why the following occurs:

the name Stack Overflow is 13 letters + 1 empty space long **(14 in total)** here's what it looks like next to a `14ch` wide element

```css
span:nth-child(2) {
  width: 14ch;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<span>Stack Overflow</span>
<span></span>
```

### How all of that relates to my question:

If the measurement of `1ch` was actually equivalent of the width of 1 character in the font, then I would simply count how many characters there are in my *old content* and use that as a negative margin for the *new content*

It appears to me that it isn't and so with all that out of the way here is my...

### Question

How do I improve the accuracy of `ch` in my case. Improving it here also includes using an entirely different approach - like `calc()` if that's what needs to happen.

### Desired Effect:

An intuitive way to figure out the length of *old content* so I can easily figure out how much negative margin to add to *new content*

### Limitations:

There are many other ways to do this. I went through all of this effort to keep things in **pure CSS**

### Code:

I've set up a sandbox which emulates different scenarios for your convenience:

```css
/* essential CSS */

.content a.swap {
  color: transparent;
}

a.swap:after {
  content: "New fancy Stuff";
  display: inline;
  margin-left: -10.8ch; /* <-- focus on this thing here */
  color: red
}


/* demo fluff */

a {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover,
a.swap:hover:after {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

a.swap:hover:after {
  color: blue !important;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.content {
  width: 300px;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 2em auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h4> No swap</h4><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, utinam libris ocurreret an mei. Case falli tibique cum id, qui unum erroribus vituperata ne. Eu mei paulo posidonium, ex fastidii recteque has. Blandit senserit eum ne, <a href="#">Old ugly stuff</a> at vel mollis deserunt liberavisse. Pro at timeam dignissim reprimique. Illum falli ei sed, eum in enim hinc recusabo, ex mei integre admodum.</span>
</div>

<hr>


<div class="content">
  <h4> Swap</h4><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, utinam libris ocurreret an mei. Case falli tibique cum id, qui unum erroribus vituperata ne. Eu mei paulo posidonium, ex fastidii recteque has. Blandit senserit eum ne, <a class="swap" href="#">old ugly stuff</a> at vel mollis deserunt liberavisse. Pro at timeam dignissim reprimique. Illum falli ei sed, eum in enim hinc recusabo, ex mei integre admodum.</span>
</div>

<hr>


<div class="content">
  <h4> No swap and partial wrap</h4><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, utinam libris ocurreret an mei. Case falli tibique cum id, qui unum erroribus vituperata ne. Eu mei paulo posidonium, ex fastidii recteque has. Blandit senserit eum ne,unum erroribus vituperata ne. Eu mei paulo posidonium erroribus  <a href="#">old ugly stuff</a> at vel mollis deserunt liberavisse. Pro at timeam dignissim reprimique. Illum falli ei sed, eum in enim hinc recusabo, ex mei integre admodum.</span>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="content">
  <h4> Swap and partial wrap</h4><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, utinam libris ocurreret an mei. Case falli tibique cum id, qui unum erroribus vituperata ne. Eu mei paulo posidonium, ex fastidii recteque has. Blandit senserit eum ne,unum erroribus vituperata ne. Eu mei paulo posidonium erroribus  <a class="swap" href="#">old ugly stuff</a> at vel mollis deserunt liberavisse. Pro at timeam dignissim reprimique. Illum falli ei sed, eum in enim hinc recusabo, ex mei integre admodum.</span>
</div>

<hr>


<div class="content">
  <h4> No swap and full wrap</h4><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, utinam libris ocurreret an mei. Case falli tibique cum id, qui unum erroribus vituperata ne. Eu mei paulo posidonium, ex fastidii recteque has. Blandit senserit eum ne,unum erroribus vituperata ne. Eu mei paulo posidonium erroribus qui unum <a href="#">old ugly stuff</a> at vel mollis deserunt liberavisse. Pro at timeam dignissim reprimique. Illum falli ei sed, eum in enim hinc recusabo, ex mei integre admodum.</span>
</div>

<hr>


<div class="content">
  <h4> Swap and full wrap</h4><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, utinam libris ocurreret an mei. Case falli tibique cum id, qui unum erroribus vituperata ne. Eu mei paulo posidonium, ex fastidii recteque has. Blandit senserit eum ne,unum erroribus vituperata ne. Eu mei paulo posidonium erroribus qui unum <a class="swap" href="#">old ugly stuff</a> at vel mollis deserunt liberavisse. Pro at timeam dignissim reprimique. Illum falli ei sed, eum in enim hinc recusabo, ex mei integre admodum.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: If you use a monospaced font - then 1ch will be the width of all characters. There are actually many commonly used monospaced fonts such as Roboto - here are some: https://hail2u.github.io/mn/

Comment: Yeah, if you're playing around with CSS anyway, just give the old content a monospaced font. That's all.

Comment: @Danield Ehm, the browser's `monospace` keyword will work fine; no need to download another font file. Remember this is for displaying invisible content!

Comment: Since you understand that proportional width fonts don't all have equal width glyphs, how do you conclude that the ch unit, representing the width of the 0 glyph specifically, is suitable for your use case, and more importantly, why do you imply in your title that the ch is somehow not as accurate as it's supposed to be?

Comment: @Danield Monospaced font are a great idea! but it will still require case-by-case fine tuning... unless I change the font for the entire document.  See [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5qxkd3cf/)

Comment: @MrLister Using the browsers default font is fantastic. However, please note my comment above

Comment: @BoltClock You're right, it's not suitable as it is bu. The only reason I'm using it is because it's the closest thing to what I want to achieve. My reasoning is that It's much easier to count the characters in a sentence than it is to try and figure out its `width` in `pixels` or `em`

Comment: I posted an answer now, but I just realised that I'm not sure if I'm missing anything. I don't know what you mean with the difference between "partial wrap" and "full wrap"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I'd do is not make the old content transparent, but set its font size to 0. Then you won't have to calculate the left margin for the new content.

```css
/* essential CSS */

.content a.swap {
  font-size:0;
}

.content a.swap:after {
  content: "New fancy Stuff";
  display: inline;
  font-size: 1rem; /* Restore font size to what it would have been */
   /* margin-left: -14ch; */ /* not needed */
  color: red
}


/* demo fluff */

.content a {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.content a:not(.swap):hover,    /* changed to match new situation */
.content a.swap:hover:after {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.content {
  width: 300px;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 2em auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h4> No swap</h4><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, utinam libris ocurreret an mei. Case falli tibique cum id, qui unum erroribus vituperata ne. Eu mei paulo posidonium, ex fastidii recteque has. Blandit senserit eum ne, <a href="#">Old ugly stuff</a> at vel mollis deserunt liberavisse. Pro at timeam dignissim reprimique. Illum falli ei sed, eum in enim hinc recusabo, ex mei integre admodum.</span>
</div>

<hr>


<div class="content">
  <h4> Swap</h4><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, utinam libris ocurreret an mei. Case falli tibique cum id, qui unum erroribus vituperata ne. Eu mei paulo posidonium, ex fastidii recteque has. Blandit senserit eum ne, <a class="swap" href="#">old ugly stuff</a> at vel mollis deserunt liberavisse. Pro at timeam dignissim reprimique. Illum falli ei sed, eum in enim hinc recusabo, ex mei integre admodum.</span>
</div>

<hr>


<div class="content">
  <h4> No swap and partial wrap</h4><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, utinam libris ocurreret an mei. Case falli tibique cum id, qui unum erroribus vituperata ne. Eu mei paulo posidonium, ex fastidii recteque has. Blandit senserit eum ne,unum erroribus vituperata ne. Eu mei paulo posidonium erroribus  <a href="#">old ugly stuff</a> at vel mollis deserunt liberavisse. Pro at timeam dignissim reprimique. Illum falli ei sed, eum in enim hinc recusabo, ex mei integre admodum.</span>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="content">
  <h4> Swap and partial wrap</h4><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, utinam libris ocurreret an mei. Case falli tibique cum id, qui unum erroribus vituperata ne. Eu mei paulo posidonium, ex fastidii recteque has. Blandit senserit eum ne,unum erroribus vituperata ne. Eu mei paulo posidonium erroribus  <a class="swap" href="#">old ugly stuff</a> at vel mollis deserunt liberavisse. Pro at timeam dignissim reprimique. Illum falli ei sed, eum in enim hinc recusabo, ex mei integre admodum.</span>
</div>

<hr>


<div class="content">
  <h4> No swap and full wrap</h4><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, utinam libris ocurreret an mei. Case falli tibique cum id, qui unum erroribus vituperata ne. Eu mei paulo posidonium, ex fastidii recteque has. Blandit senserit eum ne,unum erroribus vituperata ne. Eu mei paulo posidonium erroribus qui unum <a href="#">old ugly stuff</a> at vel mollis deserunt liberavisse. Pro at timeam dignissim reprimique. Illum falli ei sed, eum in enim hinc recusabo, ex mei integre admodum.</span>
</div>

<hr>


<div class="content">
  <h4> Swap and full wrap</h4><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, utinam libris ocurreret an mei. Case falli tibique cum id, qui unum erroribus vituperata ne. Eu mei paulo posidonium, ex fastidii recteque has. Blandit senserit eum ne,unum erroribus vituperata ne. Eu mei paulo posidonium erroribus qui unum <a class="swap" href="#">old ugly stuff</a> at vel mollis deserunt liberavisse. Pro at timeam dignissim reprimique. Illum falli ei sed, eum in enim hinc recusabo, ex mei integre admodum.</span>
</div>
```

Note: this method does have the disadvantage of needing to know what the original font-size of the <a> was. I'm assuming 1rem here, but you will have to change that into the actual size.

Comment: Pssh, I think you can restore the font size by using `font-size: initial;` in your `::after` pseudo-selector.

Comment: @KarelG No you can't; the initial value for font-size is `medium`.

Answer (score 0):

NOTICE: This piece of codes ONLY works on Firefox.

```
a::before {
  content: "New fancy content\202e";
  position: relative;
  top: 100000px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  margin-right: -1000px;

}
a::after {
  content: "\202d";
}
a {
  position: relative;
  top: -100000px;
}
```

```css
a::before {
      content: "New fancy content\202e";
      position: relative;
      top: 100000px;
      white-space: pre-wrap;
      margin-right: -1000px;
      
    }
    a::after {
      content: "\202d";
    }
    a {
      position: relative;
      top: -100000px;
    }
    
    

a {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover,
a.swap:hover:after {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

a.swap:hover:after {
  color: blue !important;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.content {
  width: 300px;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 2em auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
          <h4> No swap</h4><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, utinam libris ocurreret an mei. Case falli tibique cum id, qui unum erroribus vituperata ne. Eu mei paulo posidonium, ex fastidii recteque has. Blandit senserit eum ne, <a href="#">Old ugly stuff</a> at vel mollis deserunt liberavisse. Pro at timeam dignissim reprimique. Illum falli ei sed, eum in enim hinc recusabo, ex mei integre admodum.</span>
        </div>

        <hr>


        <div class="content">
          <h4> Swap</h4><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, utinam libris ocurreret an mei. Case falli tibique cum id, qui unum erroribus vituperata ne. Eu mei paulo posidonium, ex fastidii recteque has. Blandit senserit eum ne, <a class="swap" href="#">old ugly stuff</a> at vel mollis deserunt liberavisse. Pro at timeam dignissim reprimique. Illum falli ei sed, eum in enim hinc recusabo, ex mei integre admodum.</span>
        </div>

        <hr>


        <div class="content">
          <h4> No swap and partial wrap</h4><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, utinam libris ocurreret an mei. Case falli tibique cum id, qui unum erroribus vituperata ne. Eu mei paulo posidonium, ex fastidii recteque has. Blandit senserit eum ne,unum erroribus vituperata ne. Eu mei paulo posidonium erroribus  <a href="#">old ugly stuff</a> at vel mollis deserunt liberavisse. Pro at timeam dignissim reprimique. Illum falli ei sed, eum in enim hinc recusabo, ex mei integre admodum.</span>
        </div>

        <hr>

        <div class="content">
          <h4> Swap and partial wrap</h4><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, utinam libris ocurreret an mei. Case falli tibique cum id, qui unum erroribus vituperata ne. Eu mei paulo posidonium, ex fastidii recteque has. Blandit senserit eum ne,unum erroribus vituperata ne. Eu mei paulo posidonium erroribus  <a class="swap" href="#">old ugly stuff</a> at vel mollis deserunt liberavisse. Pro at timeam dignissim reprimique. Illum falli ei sed, eum in enim hinc recusabo, ex mei integre admodum.</span>
        </div>

        <hr>


        <div class="content">
          <h4> No swap and full wrap</h4><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, utinam libris ocurreret an mei. Case falli tibique cum id, qui unum erroribus vituperata ne. Eu mei paulo posidonium, ex fastidii recteque has. Blandit senserit eum ne,unum erroribus vituperata ne. Eu mei paulo posidonium erroribus qui unum <a href="#">old ugly stuff</a> at vel mollis deserunt liberavisse. Pro at timeam dignissim reprimique. Illum falli ei sed, eum in enim hinc recusabo, ex mei integre admodum.</span>
        </div>

        <hr>


        <div class="content">
          <h4> Swap and full wrap</h4><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, utinam libris ocurreret an mei. Case falli tibique cum id, qui unum erroribus vituperata ne. Eu mei paulo posidonium, ex fastidii recteque has. Blandit senserit eum ne,unum erroribus vituperata ne. Eu mei paulo posidonium erroribus qui unum <a class="swap" href="#">old ugly stuff</a> at vel mollis deserunt liberavisse. Pro at timeam dignissim reprimique. Illum falli ei sed, eum in enim hinc recusabo, ex mei integre admodum.</span>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I tested it on FF and it seams to work even though I'm not sure why all the links changed into New content (including the ones with no swap class). However, [No support on chrome unfortunately](https://image.ibb.co/csdNFF/Capture.png)